# How to find and kill a running Resque job on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, queue, resque, jobs

I am using [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) to process some background jobs on a Rails application.

The thing is that clients can cancel this jobs, so:

- If the job is still on the queue: dequeue it

  ```
  Resque.dequeue(GitHub::Jobs::UpdateNetworkGraph, 'repo:135325')
  ```
- If the job has finished: do nothing
- If the job is running: ???

Is there a way to programmatically find the job and in case it is running tell it to stop immediatly? My main concern is to be sure that I kill the desired job, not the current one being processed as it could be a different one form the moment I ask if it is running until the moment I kill it.

Comment: I investigated and every job is a fork of the worker, so killing the job as any other process (kill -9 'pid_number') will do the work, so, how can you know the pid of specific job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think that resque store the `process id` of the fork process, it does 
`log` it though but I dont it store the process id of the `child process forked`

you can see over [here](https://github.com/defunkt/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L137-152) in **Line 139**

With regard to your question of how extract the process id of the running resque job I think the way to do it inside your job itself using redis data-structure

so consider code below is  your perform action for a job create using redis hash(`running_process`) and add the current `process_id` in it with the current timestamp

```
class MyJob
 @queue = :myjob

 def self.perform
   field = Time.now.to_i
   redis.hsetnx "running_process",field,Process.pid 
   ### Rest of the code



   #### when the code is about to finish 
   ##remove the finish process from the 
   redis.hdel "running_process",field
  end
```

Now you can get the list of all running process by simply querying redis "running_process" hash something like this

`redis.hgetall "running_process"`

Caveats over here If the `resque` job fail then the process id  would never be clean't from

the hash what ever you do just make sure you cross check the `process id` you collect

from the redis hash is actually a `running resque job`

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like killing/stopping an ongoing job without marking it as a failed job, you can use this hack.

```
class Task

    @queue = :queue_name

    def self.perform(parameters)

        pid = Process.fork do
            Task.work parameters
        end

        #puts "parent, pid #{Process.pid}, waiting on child pid #{pid}"
        Process.wait
    end

    def self.work(parameters)
        #Your perform code here
    end
end
```

Now, where you want your stop this code, just reach to the resque worker currently doing the job which you want to stop. and kill its child's child process. Something like killing grandchild process of Worker.

**Explanation:**

A worker forks a child process in which perform function run its code. If we directly kill this child process, then this job will stop but it will be marked as failed job. That's why we have forked another child process in self.perform and now killing perform's child process will stop this running job and also, it will not be marked as failed. Now we can again enqueue the job. So, the task is to how to reach to the worker doing the job that we need to stop (._.")

I have managed to do this by writing this code for a UNIX based system:

```
Resque.workers.each do |worker|
    #If condition : "current worker is working and is working on the job that we want to stop and is operating on the queue that we require " and please change this condition as per your requirement          
    if worker.working? and worker.queues.include?("queue_name") and worker.job["payload"]["args"].first==post_id
            victim = %x[pgrep -P #{worker.pid}] #Getting child's PID
            victim.strip!
            victim = %x[pgrep -P #{victim}] #Getting grandchild's PID of worker
            victim.strip!
            %x[kill -9 #{victim.to_i}]
    end
end
```